# com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException Error while deploying jersey REST service app on weblogic

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey, weblogic12c

So i am trying to deploy a jersey REST service app on weblogic, but it is failing with this error

```
weblogic.application.ModuleException: com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException:com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.ErrorMessagesException:null
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.proces
```

Now in some other  similar questions it was suggested to download and install jersey-multipart.jar jar but that did not help. Now the thing is it was working before i moved around a few interfaces and implementations but i dont see why that should cause any problem. Here is the full log

```
<Oct 3, 2015 8:37:46 PM IST> <Error> <Console> <BEA-240003> <Administration Console encountered the following error: weblogic.application.ModuleException: com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException:com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.ErrorMessagesException:null
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processErrorMessages(Errors.java:170)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.postProcess(Errors.java:136)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:199)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:790)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:491)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:321)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:207)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:376)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:559)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:240)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:337)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:288)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.initServletInstance(StubSecurityHelper.java:98)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.createServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:86)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.createOneInstance(StubLifecycleHelper.java:71)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:31)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.initStubLifecycleHelper(ServletStubImpl.java:660)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.prepareServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:600)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadServlet(WebAppServletContext.java:1979)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.loadServletsOnStartup(WebAppServletContext.java:1956)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1846)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:2876)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1661)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:823)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:360)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:356)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:138)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:216)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:211)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:73)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:24)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:729)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:258)
    at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:48)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:80)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:587)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:339)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:846)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1275)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:442)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:176)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:548)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)`
```

Answer (score 1):

We found this issue only with one developer, using intellij and maven

When we switchted to maven 3.0.4 (bundled withw weblogic) the problem went away

Apparently something has changed in new maven version

Our env is
JDK 1.7 64 bit (in his case 1.7.0_79)
Weblogic 12.1.2

Jersey 1.17.1 bundled in weblogic
In my war file there are no jars for jersey-server or jersey-servlet